# QT setInputMask() : how to interpolate string with user input in QLineEdit

Tags: qt, qlineedit

I want the user to enter the input in QLineEdit in the following format

> Array {99, 99, 99, 99}

where

1) `Array { }` is already present in the lineEdit. User only enters comma separated integers.

2) The no. of integers entered may vary.

I tried using `setInputMask()` for task (1) (backslashes to escape characters)

```
setInputMask("\A\r\r\a\y\{99\, 99\, 99\}");
```

But this does not work. Please help.

Comment: _backslashes to escape characters_ This cannot work. Backslashes in C strings have it's own meaning which is beyond input mask: [Escape Sequences](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/escape). If at all, you have to duplicate the back-slashs.

Comment: I read it in the documentation of inputMask() http://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qlineedit.html#inputMask-prop. Thought this might work.

Comment: I just did as well. They probably assumed that reader is aware of C++ syntax. ;-)

Comment: I believe a variable number of integers separated by commas is not possible in input mask. May be, validators could be used. Otherwise, you have to overload the `QLineEdit` to achieve precisely what you want.

Comment: @SunitGautam, You can achieve it by using validators, and with a regex like this :`^Array \{(\d+(,\d+)*)?\}$`

Answer (score 0):

*Disclaimer: This is a partial answer.*

For your task (1), you should use double back-slashes to escape them. From the [documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlineedit.html#inputMask-prop) (and in your case), only the following need to be escaped: `A`, `a`, `{`, `}`.

```
setInputMask("\\Arr\\ay\\{99\\,99\\,99\\}");
```

Otherwise, the compiler would (should) warn you about `warning: unknown escape sequence: '\S'`

With task (2), an idea would be to subclass `QLineEdit`, and dynamically update the `inputMask()` at every keypress by overloading [`keyPressEvent()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlineedit.html#keyPressEvent). Another idea would be to set an input mask with, say, a hundred `99` or `x`'s then to use a [regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53704377/qt-setinputmask-how-to-interpolate-string-with-user-input-in-qlineedit/53716528#comment94264145_53704377) to validate user input.